# Pull values out of a simple STRUCT datatype

Tags: google-bigquery

Quick question! I have a table with a small STRUCT that I need to pull values out of. The STRUCT is formatted like this:

```
{
eventCategory: "foo",
eventTask: "bar",
eventName: "string"
}
```

The table schema looks like this:

```
Table schema:
Column | Datatype
----------------
Date   |  DATE
struct |  STRUCT
             eventCategory == STRING
             eventTask == STRING
             eventName == STRING
ID     |  STRING
```

The table is formatted like this:

```
  Date   |   ID   |  struct           |
---------------------------------------
20200727 | 112341 | {                 |
         |        |  eventCategory:...|
         |        |  eventTask:...    |
         |        |  eventName:...    |
         |        |  }                |
---------------------------------------
20200727 | 115632 | {                 |
         |        |  eventCategory:...|
         |        |  eventTask:...    |
         |        |  eventName:...    |
         |        |  }                |
---------------------------------------
20200727 | 115632 | {                 |
         |        |  eventCategory:...|
         |        |  eventTask:...    |
         |        |  eventName:...    |
         |        |  }                |
---------------------------------------
```

How do I query just the eventName value in a SELECT statement? Looking for an end result like:

```
  Date   |   ID   |  struct           | eventName |
---------------------------------------------------
20200727 | 112341 | {                 | "ex. 1"
         |        |  eventCategory:...|
         |        |  eventTask:...    |
         |        |  eventName:"ex. 1"|
         |        |  }                |
---------------------------------------------------
20200727 | 115632 | {                 | "ex. 2"
         |        |  eventCategory:...|
         |        |  eventTask:...    |
         |        |  eventName:"ex. 2"|
         |        |  }                |
---------------------------------------------------
20200727 | 115632 | {                 | "ex. 3"
         |        |  eventCategory:...|
         |        |  eventTask:...    |
         |        |  eventName:"ex. 3"|
         |        |  }                |
---------------------------------------------------
```

All of the values inside the STRUCT are strings.

Thanks!!

Comment: not clear  - can  you please provide more details - what exactly the type of this field(s) - providing table schema will help. also show what you tried and why it didn't work for you - this might also help undertsnad your problem in what is sounds like extremely simple and basic things

Comment: I think I added what you were looking for -- but to be honest I have never worked with STRUCT datatypes and I don't even know where to begin. All of the values inside the STRUCT field are strings

Comment: sorry. still not clear what that field is exactly! is it just free text field of STRING data type? or Array of structs of key / value - not clear! table's schema might help if you show it

Comment: I was under the impression it *was* a struct -- it is not a free text field, so that leaves it to be an array of structs?

Comment: update question with table schema and most likely this will become clear :o)

Comment: I added the schema -- it notes the field as datatype == STRUCT, with the three values inside as strings.

Comment: ok. so as I mentioned I think this ended up with basic question of how to access struct's elements - see the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *, 
  struct_column.eventName AS eventName
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

replace `struct_column` with whatever real name of that column

Comment: It was that easy! Thank you for walking me through how to organize my post as well, definitely will do that in the future =)